# ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required:

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I want to run a python script, say `train_rnn_wdcnn_loads.py` in jupyter notebook from Anaconda in Win 10.
But I constantly get this error:

```
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -data_path
```

*(I'm new in Python and still figuring out how argparse works)*

The code are:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('-data_path', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I have tried to make it works with:

```
parser.add_argument('-data_path', required=True, default="C:\\Users\\Firdaus\\Desktop\\data")
```

or from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172247/8129852):

```
args = parser.parse_args(data_path="C:\\Users\\Firdaus\\Desktop\\data")
```

and it still didn't work.

When I run the script via command line, `python train_rnn_wdcnn_loads.py -data_path C:\\Users\\Firdaus\\Desktop\\data` it works but still facing error in another python script.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
1614364082.0161884
loading data ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_rnn_wdcnn_loads.py", line 107, in <module>
    source_data = CWRUBearingData(data_path, experiment, source,
  File "C:\Users\Firdaus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\utils\cwru_data_loader.py", line 114, in __init__
    for l in self.loads:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How to run the script without error?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? Because launching the script with ```python file.py -data_path /home/your/path``` seems correct. Try to print the ```args``` to check what it contains.

Comment: yes the path is correct. what I want is launch the script within the jupyter notebook. when I launch via command line, it works.

Comment: Try to see this https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-work-with-pure-python-file-py/4443

Comment: many thanks, I will try

Answer (score 0):

If you put (required=True) in your code, it will ignore  (default="C:\Users\Firdaus\Desktop\data")

This should work:

```
parser.add_argument('-data_path', required=False, default="C:\\Users\\Firdaus\\Desktop\\data")
```