# In Visual Studio Code, how to pass arguments in launch.json

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

In Visual Studio Code, in the `launch.json` file that launches the app I'm writing, how do I add command line arguments?

Comment: An alternative way to pass arguments is to use the `%run` magic command. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78102091/3057377

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes), you need to use the `args` attribute. *E.g.*

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug App",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
            "args": ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @eigenfield have you tried filing a bug report with Visual Studio Code or Kotlin?

Comment: just to clarify args array, `"args": ["key=value", "key=value"]`

Comment: @AwaisNasir is that suggestion for Kotlin? Or in general?  In practice, I've used simple strings and not key-value pairs.

Comment: @JonathanBenn I don't know about kotlin, thats the general solution, for me key value pair solution worked and not simple strings

Comment: Alright, it seems that Your Mileage May Vary. For Node.JS, I've used a simple string (not a key-value pair) without any trouble. In any case, the input is always a string regardless what's _in_ the string.

Comment: When passing `args` to `launch.json`, the args are added to the call: `node ./test/test.js --no-warnings`. However, I need the args right after `node`:`node --no-warnings ./test/test.js`. Solution in launch.json: `"args": ["--no-warnings","${file}"]`

Comment: Hi @Timo, the placeholder `${file}` seems to get replaced by the `launch.json` file path.  Is that what happens for you?

Comment: If I run this as is, I get an error: `launch: property 'cwd' is missing or empty`. I had to manually add this line to the launch.json to get it to work

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

Answer (score 39):

I pass arguments by this way for the python program, it may work for nodejs:

```json
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug App",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
    "args": ["--arg1", "value1", "--arg2", "value2"]
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Python. Thanks

Comment: Still work perfectly for me as well :D

Answer (score 0):

In settings.json in the .vscode folder you can pass an env file.

settings.json

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "."
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/env"

}
```

and the env file

```
FLASK_ENV=test
```

Comment: `settings.json` and `launch.json` are different files for different purposes. And yes, `launch.json` exists on macOS too, it is just not created out of the blue, it is created when a run configuration is created.