# How to pass non-object arguments in launch.json for debugging in VS Code

Tags: json, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have been able to use args from the launch.json file as described in this question post
[In Visual Studio Code, how to pass arguments in launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889703/in-visual-studio-code-how-to-pass-arguments-in-launch-json)

But I want to pass in an argument without a value. When I call the executable in the shell, I call it with a single argument like so:

```
a.exe -fw
```

*where the fw arg prints out the firmware version. This works well, but I cannot simulate this in debug since I get an error that my arg needs to be an object.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "environment": ["-fw"]
    }
```

This gives me an error

```
Incorrect type. expected "object"
```

But I dont want to pass in a value, it is basically just a read argument.

How do I incorporate this in my launch.json file?
Thanks!

Comment: You can delete the question if it is due to a typo

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I realized I copy pasted my args in the "environment" pair and not the the "args"... everything works as expected

```
        "args": [
            "-fw"
        ],
```