# VS Code debugging prompting for arguments and also setting the working directory

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

I know how to pass fixed arguments in the launch.json, e.g. [In Visual Studio Code, how to pass arguments in launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889703/in-visual-studio-code-how-to-pass-arguments-in-launch-json) . What I really need is a prompt where I can give a value for an argument that changes.

In addition, my argument is a (data) directory for which there is a very ugly long absolute path. I'd really like to be able to set the working directory to a path which contains each of my individual data directories so I only need to provide a relative directory path, i.e. just the directory name.

I'm working with Python, on Windows (not my choice) using VS Code 1.55.2 (not my choice, either).

Comment: [input-variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) or [pick-file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file)

Comment: Thanks, @rioV8 . I gave input-variables a spin and that seems a workable solution. I can make this work without having to set the working directory if I just use the input variable with a constant directory string prefixed to it. Then I only need to enter the leaf. If you would like credit for the answer, feel free to submit an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [input variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables)

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File with arguments",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "args": [
        "--dir",
        "/some/fixed/dir/${input:enterDir}"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "enterDir",
      "type": "promptString",
      "description": "Subdirectory to process",
      "default": "data-0034"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can place the `${input:enterDir}` in any string in the task `"configurations"` like the `"cwd"` property.

If you like to pick a directory from a list because it is dynamic you can use the extension `Command Variable` that has the command [pickFile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file)

Command Variable v1.36.0 supports the `fixed` folder specification.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File with arguments",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "args": [
        "--dir",
        "${input:pickDir}"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickDir",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile",
      "args": {
        "include": "**/*",
        "display": "fileName",
        "description": "Subdirectory to process",
        "showDirs": true,
        "fromFolder": { "fixed": "/some/fixed/dir" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

On Unix like systems you can include the folder in the `include` glob pattern. On Windows you have to use the `fromFolder` to convert the directory path to a usable glob pattern. If you have multiple folders you can use the `predefined` property.

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answer requires specifying each command line argument by name, there is a way to get VS Code to prompt for the entire command line. This makes the solution work with any PowerShell script rather than requiring `launch.json` to be tailored to each script you are debugging. In the `configurations` block of `launch.json`, add:

```
        {
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "PowerShell Launch Current File w/Args Prompt",
            "script": "${file}",
            "args": [
                "${command:SpecifyScriptArgs}"
            ],
            "cwd": "${file}"
        }
```

The secret sauce here is the `${command:SpecifyScriptArgs}` prompt.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. Nice. This could be only valid for Powershell - and is suited to it because PowerShell does almost no command line processing in the shell and passes all the arguments to the script in $args.