# how do i find and edit the "console" .json setting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode and I need to find and edit the "console" setting in .json to change it from "integratedTerminal" to "externalTerminal". I have no real idea how to do it though.

Comment: Have you opened and looked into the user settings? If not, are you aware of what the command palette is and how to open it?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59299746/495455