# Can vscode use a profile from Properties/launchSettings.json?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to just point ".vscode/launch.json" to a profile defined in my "Properties/launchSettings.json" so I don't need to duplicate those values?

I need to support several different editors and also run from command line with

```
dotnet run --launch-profile="myprofile"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: run Python file with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704747/visual-studio-code-run-python-file-with-arguments) - its VsCode generic and applies to C# the same as Python or any other language.

Comment: This is .net specific. launchSettings.json is read by .net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is in the docs under [debugger-launchjson.md > launchSettings.json support](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/1c11b4e4d/debugger-launchjson.md#launchsettingsjson-support):

```json
"launchSettingsProfile": "${workspaceFolder}/<Relative-Path-To-Project-Directory/Properties/launchSettings.json"
```