# Visual Studio Code: How to run a python file with arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

I usually run and debug my programs from the console. Lately I have been started to run and debug from the vs code window. However I cannot do this when the program require arguments.

Searching on how to do this I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSljcz54pYQ) and yes somehow I managed to run (or more accurately debug) the script from vscode

However I have several doubts:

1. To do this I had to press Debug, never Play because Play calls the script with no arguments. With debug I can set the arguments and run it but... is this always the case?
2. The `launch.json` file that is used is saved in the `.vscode` folder, so it is not ideal for git managing, right?
3. And more importantly, if I have two scripts Scritp1 and Script2 and they both use the `launch.json` file, how can I have two files of the same name? Do I have to create and rename files every time? That sounds highly impractical

Comment: The whole vscode folder doesn't need ignored by Git. You can keep settings.json and launch.json, and devcontainers.json

Comment: this user https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047631/4451521 doesn't think the same...

Comment: The VSCode documentation (and commenters there) disagree with this one user.

Comment: An alternative way to pass arguments is to use the %run magic command. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78102091/3057377